# How to customize perl intepreter

Tags: java, perl

I am using a java application with a web UI(jsp/js). I am trying to embed a perl editor into my UI and also need a few set of my own defined syntax apart from the perl default syntaxes to be interpreted and executed by the perl engine, which I would port with my app.

1. Is it possible to edit the default perl(or any scripting lang) intepreter to add a few of my custom syntaxes into it.
2. If the first is possible, how can i embed the intepreter into my java based UI, so that I can execute any perl script using my custom intepreter within my java container (Tomcat etc)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, since version 5.14, Perl has offered an official API for defining new keywords in modules. See for example, [Switch::Plain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch::Plain), [Kavorka](https://metacpan.org/pod/Kavorka), or [Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) for examples of what can be achieved with it. (Though actually even without delving into that, Perl's syntax is quite extendable just using exporters, prototypes, operator overloading, etc.)
2. There's a document called [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) which deals with embedding Perl in a C. You can probably extend that idea to Java using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).